# How to compile Protobuf 2.6.0 for Android on Windows

Tags: android, windows, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to compile Protobuf 2.6.0 for Android on Windows.

I have to say that I need a staic Protobuf library for using with Qt 5 on Android.

In Cygwin bash I run the next command:

```
./configure --prefix=c:/Thirdparty/Android/protobuf/build \
--host=arm-linux-androideabi \
--disable-shared \
--enable-cross-compile \
--with-protoc=c:/Thirdparty/bin/protoc \
CC=c:/Thirdparty/Android/NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc.exe \
CXX=c:/Thirdparty/Android/NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++.exe \
LDFLAGS=-Lc:/Thirdparty/Android/NDK/platforms/android-5/arch-arm/usr/lib \
CPPFLAGS=-Ic:/Thirdparty/Android/NDK/platforms/android-5/arch-arm/usr/include
```

But I got the next error:

```
configure:3474: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3496: c:/Thirdparty/Android/NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc.exe  \
-Ic:/Thirdparty/Android/NDK/platforms/android-5/arch-arm/usr/include \
-Lc:/Thirdparty/Android/NDK/platforms/android-5/arch-arm/usr/lib conftest.c  >&5
c:/thirdparty/android/ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe:
error: cannot open crtbegin_dynamic.o: No such file or directory
c:/thirdparty/android/ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe:
error: cannot open crtend_android.o: No such file or directory
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What should I do else? Thank you.

Comment: So you followed the guide at https://github.com/google/protobuf? Why not take the binary at https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/downloads?

Comment: There is no binaries and hints how to make binaries for Android on Windows...

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. I had to define --sysroot="", like this:

```
LDFLAGS="-Lc:/Thirdparty/Android/NDK/platforms/android-5/arch-arm/usr/lib \
--sysroot=c:/Thirdparty/Android/NDK/platforms/android-5/arch-arm"
```